# XP to Win 7 via ethernet cable. No routers, no wireless. They can't ping each other

Tags: networking, ethernet, tcpip, wired-networking

I've got a windows XP machine and a windows 7 laptop connected by an ethernet cable. The xp has static ip address  169.254.84.221 and the windows 7 has 169.254.84.220. both subnet masks 255.255.255.0.

They can't ping each other (Or do anything else for that matter)  edit: wierdly enough they can play each other at Unreal Tournament gotye :P testing the sequels now.

using the ping command just gives request timed out over and over again.

I've rebooted both machines and repaired the network and troubleshot the network etc. nothing has changed. What should I try next?

Comment: Make sure both computers are in the same "workgroup".

Comment: WHy are you using a 169.* IP address? I think you're supposed to use 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: @cloneman, you are correct. The RFCs say that you cannot change the mask for the link-local addressing, it must be `/16` or `255.255.0.0`, and you are not allowed to statically configure an address in the link-local range, it must be chosen via pseudo-random generation.

Answer (score 1):

Firewall software on each machine may have ICMP (ping) responses disabled.  Try turning all firewall settings off for both machines and see if pings start working.

Unreal Tournament is probably using UDP (or maybe TCP) and so isn't affected by the disabled ICMP.

Answer (score 0):

- The OS are seeing direct connections and freaking out. The game probably works because it's not such a "raw" thing, and thus the OS' firewall or anything is blocking the weird, unexpected connection. You need to set it up in a special way. We did this in class a year ago, but I completely forgot how.
- You're not using the right cable.

Those two things should help you solve your problem:

http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Two-Computers

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071106172317AAluqip